# Why is openssl AES producing a different result than every online tool I try?

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

I am trying to encrypt a string using AES.

On my Macbook, I enter the command

```
echo -n "hello" | openssl enc -e -aes-128-cbc
```

and enter the key `123456`.

Result: `U2FsdGVkX1+FBre1MZ1YDfgZRmRyt/hMogfMhYeiq8Q=`

Howevr, when I then try any online enryption tool, I get a different result.

For example, with this site, [encode-decode](https://encode-decode.com/aes-128-cbc-encrypt-online/) using the same encryption scheme, I get

`NrjrStoGrmkLAvWaJuKtvg==`

Why the difference ? What configuration am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce either of your results(I'm not on Mac). The issue is likely have to do with the fact that CBC is a block cipher, which means it takes a fix lenght of 16 bytes of blocks for each encryption cycle(unlike stream ciphers). When you have less than 16 bytes of data, it will use padding.

[image: AES-CBC mode]

*Why the difference ?* 
The AES standard doesn't define(.. I know, this is not very helpful for us) what kind of padding needs to be used, so it can differ in the implementation between PKCS #5 or PKCS #7.

In my case I was even hinted to use this instead of the operation you chose `*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used. Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.` the `-pbkdf2` option in openssl corresponds to PKCS #5. 
We don't really have information about what library the online tool is using for the same operation.
Regarding the results:

```
U2FsdGVkX1+FBre1MZ1YDfgZRmRyt/hMogfMhYeiq8Q= and 
NrjrStoGrmkLAvWaJuKtvg==
```

Base64 decode to the following, respectively:

```
Salted__1XFdrL̅
6Ji&⭾
```

So from this, you can see, that the output of openssl encryption also uses a salt, but even then the content is completely different.

*What configuration am I missing ?*
Altough, you could try the following:

```
 openssl enc -e -aes-128-cbc -pbkdf2 -nosalt
```

Salts are present to protect against brute force attacks concerning the private key used, for instance if multiple encrypted documents are gathered, and during the decryption they won't matter. It will simply be a unique hint for the decryption, and will be eliminated durng the process, but eliminates some attacks.

The question is, how you are going to use the encryption scheme going forward - as long as you use openssl consistently, you can be assured that it will work, although a quick googling revealed that different versions [can change](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403320) and even effect that, which is why I likely why I cannot decrypt the data provided on OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018.
Also, here is an [article](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2017/01/17/tutorial-aes-encryption-and-decryption-with-openssl/) with some good examples and explanations.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: To reproduce the posted ciphertext `NrjrStoGrmkLAvWaJuKtvg==` on the posted [website](https://encode-decode.com/aes-128-cbc-encrypt-online/) for the default setting AES-128-CBC and the plaintext `hello`, the key `12345678` (and **not** `123456` as posted) must be applied.

The website uses [PKCS7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) padding. The key is encoded with UTF8 and padded with `0x00` values to the required length (16 bytes for AES 128). In CBC mode a zero vector is applied as IV. Since this is not described (at least I did not find a documentation), this can only be deduced by a comparison with a reference-implementation or -website.

In OpenSSL the key is specified with the `-K` option (in hexdigits), see [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-enc.html). If an IV is applied this IV must be specified with the `-iv` option (also in hexdigits). So to get the same result as the website, you need to add to the OpenSSL statement:

```
-K 31323334353637380000000000000000 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

If no key is passed, OpenSSL asks for a password, generates a random 8 bytes salt and derives a key and IV from salt and password using the OpenSSL function [`EVP_BytesToKey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html). By default, the digest SHA256 is used (as of version 1.1.0 inclusive, before MD5) and an iteration count of 1. The output format is the ASCII encoding of `Salted__`, followed by the 8 bytes salt and the actual ciphertext, all Base64 encoded. Therefore the ciphertext always starts with `U2FsdGVkX1`. Since the salt is determined *randomly* for each encryption, different keys and IVs and thus different ciphertexts result each time. Key and IV can be displayed with the `-p` option.

With the password `123456` (as posted) and the digest MD5, the posted OpenSSL ciphertext `U2FsdGVkX1+FBre1MZ1YDfgZRmRyt/hMogfMhYeiq8Q=` can be decrypted to the plaintext `hello`. The `-p` option can also be used for decryption and reveals:

```
Key: F1A16DEEFFEE4AB705BB72C21C1F1CA2 
IV:  000A7A05E99BF90C025EFE40B534E836
```

Vice versa, this key and IV can be used to encrypt the plaintext `hello` directly, resulting in the ciphertext `F819466472B7F84CA207CC8587A2ABC4`. If the posted OpenSSL ciphertext `U2FsdGVkX1+FBre1MZ1YDfgZRmRyt/hMogfMhYeiq8Q=` is Base64 decoded and the first 16 bytes (prefix and salt) are discarded, then the same ciphertext results, as expected.

It should be noted that the key derivation used by OpenSSL is not very secure, [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29139). Since version 1.1.1, OpenSSL supports PBKDF2, but this must be explicitly specified.